# A new row of data in the table in jscrollpane don't scroll?

Tags: java, jtable, jpanel, jscrollpane

I use the following code to show the statistics in the table. Every time the data in the hashmap is changed, I run the following code again. Although the newly added row will show, it can't scroll(like this[image]). So anyone knows why? Thanks.

```
 HashMap<String, Commodity> duMap = Light.getLightMap();

            String[] column = {"Name", "Type", "Amount", "Default in price", "Default out price", "Last in price", "Last out price"};
            String[][] row = new String[duMap.size()][];
            int i = 0;
            for (String string : duMap.keySet()) {
                duLight = duMap.get(string);
                row[i] = new String[]{duLight.getName(), duLight.getModel(), ""+duLight.getAmount(), ""+duLight.getDefaultIP(), ""+duLight.getDefaultOP(), ""+duLight.getLastIP(), ""+duLight.getLastOP()};
                i ++;
            }
            JTable statistics = new JTable(row, column);
            statistics.setEnabled(false);
            statistics.setFont(new Font("DIALOG", 2, 20));
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                statistics.getColumnModel().getColumn(j).setPreferredWidth(120);
            }
            statistics.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
            statistics.setRowHeight(40);

            statistics.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, dtc);

            //back is a static panel
            back.add(new JScrollpane(statistics), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            back.revalidate();
```

Comment: It looks like your not removing the old scrollpane/table, having said that, your approach is incredibly inefficient. A a better solution would be to devise a TableModel that could wrap your HashMap and then provide a simple method (in the table model) to tell when new rows have been added and allow it to trigger an update

Comment: @MadProgrammer Any examples? I am new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a new JTable and JScrollPane all the time you can try:

1. Just updating the existing DefaultTableModel by using the `setDataVector(...)` method.
2. Or, you create create a new DefaultTableModel and then update the JTable by using the `setModel(...)` method.

Comment: Could you show me some examples, I am new and don't know get what you mean.

Comment: For suggestion 2, you can read the DefaultTableModel API. It has a constructor where you provide the column names and data. Then once you create the DefaultTableModel you add it to the existing JTable using the setModel() method. Again read the JTable API for information about that method. There is no need to create a new table or scrollpane. All the code is doing is updating the data in the existing table. You can always search the forum for examples that use the setModel() method.